# Planning perspective in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse

Previous versions of Eclipse had a planning perspective with a task view for viewing tasks from a task repository.  I cannot find this in Eclipse Juno, nor can I find any plugin to install for it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend on the specific package that you use.

The "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" package includes Mylyn out of the box:
Menu Window, Open Perspective, Other..., Planning opens the perspective, or Window, Show View, ..., Mylyn, Task List for just the task list.

Access to Bugzilla and Gerrit is also included, for other task repositories you need to install more connectors, for example via either Help, Eclipse Marketplace...

Comment: The "Compare Packages" web page http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php for juno lists Mylyn as included for pretty much everything but the "Classic" configuration.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Mylyn connector for github 'issues' is best fetched from Help, Eclipse Marketplace, ...  When instead trying to install it from the Mylyn Tasks view via Add Repository, ..., Add Connector, ..., Github, .. that fails because it seems to point to a version for Eclipse 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it in Help->Install new software.  Select to work with "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno", and under the Collaboration tab is an option "Mylyn Tasks Connector: Bugzilla".